# How to run child processes simultaneously? in c

Tags: c, fork

So here is my code that will take an int as an command line argument then fork N child processes (That run simultaneously). And then when each child ends, the parent will echo the child that child exit status.

But right now I can only do child by child but not simultaneously. How can I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int i, pid, ran;

    for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
    pid = fork();
    srand(time(NULL));
    ran = (rand() % 10) + 1 ;

     if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
     } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
        printf("Sleep for = %d\n", ran);
        sleep(ran);
        exit(ran); 
     } else  {
        int status = 0;
        pid_t childpid = wait(&status);
        printf("Parent knows child %d is finished. \n", (int)childpid);
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run two child processes simultaneously in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479194/how-to-run-two-child-processes-simultaneously-in-c)

Comment: the function: `srand()` should only be called once, not every time through the loop

Comment: before using `argv[1]`, the code needs to compare `argc` with 2 to assure the `argv[1]` parameter exists,  if `argc` is < 2 then output a 'usage' message and exit

Comment: the code does not compile cleanly.  it is missing `#include <sys/wait.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`   Always enable all warnings when compiling (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: Please indent the code consistently.  That makes is much easier to read/understand by us humans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `wait()` inside of the loop where you're spawning the children, so it won't continue the loop to start the next child until the current one is done.

You need to call `wait()` outside of the loop in a separate loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int i, pid, ran;

    for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
        pid = fork();
        srand(time(NULL));
        ran = (rand() % 10) + 1 ;

         if (pid < 0) {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
         } else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
            printf("Sleep for = %d\n", ran);
            sleep(ran);
            exit(ran); 
         }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
        int status = 0;
        pid_t childpid = wait(&status);
        printf("Parent knows child %d is finished. \n", (int)childpid);
    }
}
```